# Apply style to an element

Tags: html, css

I got this style for the scrollbar. But how do I apply it to a div that has overflow-y: scroll?

Any idea how to do this?

```css
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.something {
height:200px;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="something">
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
<p>adasda</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you include jQuery in your snippet?

Answer (score 1):

To add custom `scrollbar` styling to above `div`, you need to add `width` property in your above codes, as below.

```css
.something {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll; /*Adding scrollbar to div on content overflow*/ 
}

.something::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  /*This serves as background of scrollbar. Add background color to see the difference*/
  width: 20px;
}

.something::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.something::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 /*This styles the above scroll-track which automatically resize as page size increases or decrease, change background color and see the difference*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
  <p>adasda</p>
</div>
```

**Note :-** Following **scrollbar** styling doesn't works on **Firefox and IE/EDGE**, check for support on caniuse.com and do include vendor-prefix for other browsers.

Comment: Check this link to read more about other pseudo elements that scrollbar consist of. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

Comment: do you know any other similar scroll bar that works on all browsers?

Comment: In that case you need to use some js plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add the scrollbar styles to the class?

```
.something::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5; 
}
```

And then just apply the class to your list?